# Transform string to date format ( from week number )

Tags: date, teradata

I have a string with week numbers from 1 - 53 ( split weeks from 2015 ) and years in the form of:

```
    Date_ID
    KW01/2016
    KW35/2014
    KW51/2014
    KW53/2015
    KW12/2014
    KW03/2016
    ...
```

and I want to transform the whole column to date format ( monday for start date is sufficient )

I tried

```
sel cast(substr(Date_ID,3,7) as date format 'ww/yyyy')  from database
```

but ww is not the abbreviation for week numbers and I'm not finding a way arround it. Is conversion from weeks to date even possible with teradata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is use to sys_calendar table in Teradata. It has weeks of year and other stuff. Below is the code.

```
insert into test values('KW01/2016');   
insert into test values('KW35/2014');   
insert into test values('KW51/2014');   
insert into test values('KW53/2015');   
insert into test values('KW12/2014');  
insert into test values('KW03/2016');   


select       calendar_date   
from         test a    
inner join   sys_calendar.calendar b    
on          substr(name,3, 2) = b.week_of_year       
and         substr(name,6, 4) =b.year_of_calendar    
and         day_of_week = 2
```

The day_of_week = 2 gives you Monday. If you want Sunday change it to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Those week number seem to be based on ISO while Teradata's `sys_calendar.calendar` is based on US weeks.

There's another `sys_calendar.business_calendar` which can be set to ISO using `set session calendar = iso`, but the implementation is totally flawed :)

Now the good news: There usually exists a calendar created by your company with lots of pre-calculated columns and one of them might/should be `year/week`. Then it's simply a join like `Date_ID = yearweekcolumn and dayofweek = monday`.

Or you use a UDF I wrote some years ago, modified to your input:

```
-- Calculate the first day of an ISO week (monday)
REPLACE FUNCTION isoweek_to_date(isoweek VARCHAR(9))
RETURNS DATE
SPECIFIC isoweek_to_date_c
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
      (((CAST(SUBSTRING(isoweek FROM 6 FOR 4) AS INT) -1900) * 10000 + 104) (DATE))
  +    ((CAST(SUBSTRING(isoweek FROM 3 FOR 2) AS INT) - 1) * 7)
  - (((((CAST(SUBSTRING(isoweek FROM 6 FOR 4) AS INT) -1900) * 10000 + 104) (DATE)) - DATE '0001-01-01') MOD 7)
;
```

`isoweek_to_date('KW01/2016')` returns `2016-01-04

Comment: Your right, there is a table to get ISO weeknumbers in our data ware house! Thanks to both of you